# lastList function in a list without calling a Prelude in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have this function lastList that is suppose to call the last element of a list. I need to do manually, without predefined "last" in Prelude.
I have this code so far

```
lastList :: List a -> a
lastList list = case list of
    Empty -> error "List is empty"
    Cons _ xs -> lastList xs
```

It gives me an output "List is empty" with the list

```
test3 :: List Double
test3 = Cons 1.3 (Cons 5.2 (Cons 3.0 (Cons 8.7 (Cons 9.1 Empty))))
```

What is the problem? Thank you

Comment: You forgot to write the "success" case, where you actually find the last element, and return it!

Answer (score 6):

**The problem**: you only define `Empty` as basecase, which will error. So every non-infinite list, will eventually result in the `Empty` basecase, and error. Infinite lists will loop forever, but that is something we can not circumvent since infinite lists simply have no last element.

Since the `List` is a linked list with a `head` (which is an element) and a `tail` (which is the rest of the list) as `Cons head tail` and a `Empty`, a list with one element is thus `Cons x Empty`. So that means in case we obtain such a pattern, we should return `x`.

Furthermore in case the `tail` is not `Empty`, we should perform recursion on the tail, until we obtain a list with only one element left.

In case the list is `Empty`, the list is empty, and thus we should error on this input.

```
lastList :: List a -> a
lastList Empty = error "List is empty"
lastList (Cons x Empty) = x
lastList (Cons _ xs) = lastList xs
```